# Rails AXSLX sort.cells

Tags: ruby-on-rails, axlsx

I'm using `gem 'axlsx_rails'` in a Rails app.

I would like to sort cells (row 2 through 23 on column A) as the last step in creating a tab.

Here is the code I have:

```
wb.add_worksheet(:name => "Cost") do |sheet|
  sheet.page_setup.set :orientation => :portrait
  sheet.add_row ['Seq', 'Category', 'Remarks', 'Amount', 'Notes'], :style => [header_cell, header_cell, header_cell, header_cell, header_cell]
    @costproject.costestimates.each do |costestimate|
      sheet.add_row [costestimate.costcat.position, costestimate.costcat.category_name, costestimate.costcat.categorydesc, number_with_precision(costestimate.amount, :precision => 2), costestimate.notes], :style=> [intgr,nil,nil,money]
    end
  sheet.add_row [nil, 'TOTAL', nil, "=SUM(D2:D23)"]
  sheet.column_widths 5, 35, 25, 25
  cells.sort ?????
end
```

I assume this can be done. Is that right?
If yes, how?  What do I replace `cells.sort ?????` with?

Thanks for your help!

Update 1:

Thanks to emcanes, I sorted the records during the add_row:

```
       sheet.add_row ['Seq', 'Category', 'Remarks', 'Amount', 'Notes'], :style => [header_cell, header_cell, header_cell, header_cell, header_cell]
    @costproject.costestimates.includes(:costcat).order("costcats.position").each do |ce|
      sheet.add_row [ce.costcat.position, ce.costcat.category_name,  ce.costcat.categorydesc, number_with_precision(ce.amount, :precision => 2), ce.notes], :style=> [intgr,border,border,money,border]
    end
```

I would still like to know if AXSLX can use `cells.sort`??

Comment: Why not just sort the data prior to the insert?

Comment: The sort field comes from a referenced table/field that gets inserted.  I tried to sort it - but, maybe I need to go back and make it work that way.  I'll give it a try.  I would still like to know if `cells.sort` works.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `rows` SimpleTypedList is available through the worksheet, and though there is no `sheet.rows=` method, you can use `sort_by!` to modify it in place:

```
wb.add_worksheet(:name => "Cost") do |sheet|
  # your other code
  first_row = sheet.rows.first
  last_row  = sheet.rows.last
  # get a total position higher than all others
  tpos = sheet.rows.map {|row| row.cells[0].value.to_i}.max + 1
  sheet.rows.sort_by! do |row|
    (row == first_row ? -1 : (row == last_row ? tpos : row.cells[0].value.to_i))
  end
  # now do styling
end
```

There is no internal index for a row, so you can't ask what index it is. It simply finds out where it is located in the rows list if you ask it. So you have to save the title/total rows ahead of time.

I've not tested the styling, but I'm not at all sure it would follow the sort, since this is messing with Axlsx internals. It may need to happen after, unless it is generic.

And, incidentally, use the `Axlsx::cell_r` function to get your total range:

```
"=SUM(D2:#{Axlsx::cell_r(3,@costproject.costestimates.length)}"
```

Since it expects zero based indices, the actual length will count the title row. 22 estimates will give you "D23".